# Pandas.to_excel rounding my decimal values up to 2 decimal places, but gives accurate results when converted to_csv

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dataframe with large set of records.

When this dataframe is converted to CSV it give accurate results with all digits after decimals. However the same dataframe when converted to excel (xlsx) then the Decimal Values get rounded off in the Excel sheet (most of them up to two decimal places).

**For example:**

**CSV output: 3363.6499999999999**

**Excel output: 3363.65**

I am writing the output in output=BytesIO() to save the Excel in S3 using "put(output.getvalue())"

```
output= BytesIO()
writer=pd.ExcelWriter(output)
df.to_excel(writer, index=  False)
writer.save()
```

I do not want to round. I would like my actual value without any changes. How do I convert to_excel without rounding?

Answer (score 4):

Try this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date':['1/15/2016','2/1/2016','2/15/2016','3/15/2016'],
        'numA':[1000,2000,3000,4000.3],
        'numB':[10000,20000.2,30000,40000]
    })

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:/.../pandas_excel_test.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00'})
worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, format1)  # Adds formatting to column C
writer.save()
```

You can change the format `0.00` in the `.add_format({'num_format': '0.00'})` on your desired format, for example, `0.0000` for four decimal places. Note this only applies to column C.

If you want to change the formatting of all columns, modify the `worksheet.set_column('C:C', None, format1)`, for example

```
worksheet.set_column(0, 3, None, format1)
```

where 0 the first column and 3 the final column.

Check more formatting here: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html

Comment: I  don't know which columns will be float actually. How to set it to global?

Comment: If for global, you just set the `0:n` where n is the number of columns.  For example, `worksheet.set_column('0:3', None, format1)` # for all n columns.

Comment: I have set ```worksheet.set_column('0:3', None, format1)``` but getting **NoneType, object has no attribute 'group'** error

Comment: sorry, it should be `worksheet.set_column(0, 3, None, format1)` if you´re using column numbers

Comment: It's not doing the job. I am not getting the exact values :(

Comment: openpyxl seems to be the default these days, and its implementation of Book (or Workbook) doesn't have a `.add_format` method?

Answer (score 1):

Another example:

```
import xlsxwriter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:/.../pandas_excel_test.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')

workbook  = writer.book
cell_format1 = workbook.add_format()
cell_format1.set_num_format('0.000')
worksheet.write(1, 0, 3.1415926, cell_format1)
```

[Result](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_num_format)

```
3.142
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new here, would you be able to round to 2 decimal places using this?

```
df['col_name'].apply(lambda x: round(x, 2))
```

Comment: I don't want to round. I want my actual value without any changes.

Comment: @Naveen, I have a silly suggestion: how about pandas convert to_csv, then in Excel, Save As xlsx, possible?

Comment: We were doing that till now. But the framework generates many csv and converting all into Excel is not possible. So making this excel generator